# How to use RevealRootLayoutContentEvent for designing of the GWT 2.0 layout system in GWTP?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-platform, gwtp

I have just heard about `RevealRootLayoutContentEvent` yesterday. I have no idea of how to use it whatsoever in GWTP.

Ok, i am using GWTP on eClipse to crease a presenter like the following picture
[image]

We first need to select `RevealRootLayoutContentEvent` when create the Presenter, eClipse will generate some file, then what to do next?

Can anyone give me an a very simple example of how to use `RevealRootLayoutContentEvent` in GWTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels

If you use RevealRootLayoutContentEvent your application will be put inside [RootLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootLayoutPanel.html). In this case you should avoid using no-"...Layout..." panels.

If you use RevealRootContentEvent [RootPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html) will be used.